# What for catkin needs to link to librt (realtime extension)?

Tags: ros, catkin, realtime, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Setting aside my knowledge about build system is limited,)

There's a macro in catkin: [catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/85556d6776337e9cb1970f0f1733687dbbcb8a42/cmake/tools/rt.cmake), inside of which it tries to find `librt` I think. Does `catkin` need realtime extension for:

- building `catkin` itself?

OR

- building whatever packages that require `rt`?

or both?

I'm wondering, because while trying to build `catkin` workspace from source (following [this doc](http://ros.org/rosdoclite/groovy/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/underlay.html)) on non-Ubuntu platform (`QNX`), I get this error:

```
# cd catkinws && mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../src
:
-- Found gtest sources under '/home/rosuer/catkin_ws/src/gtest': gtests will be built
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/assert.cmake:17 (message):
  
  Assertion failed: check for file existence, but filename
  (RT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND) unset.  Message: RT Library

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake:42 (assert_file_exists)
  catkin/cmake/all.cmake:134 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

While remaining not so sure, I modified [a line](https://github.com/ros/catkin/blob/85556d6776337e9cb1970f0f1733687dbbcb8a42/cmake/tools/rt.cmake#L34) of `rt.cmake` as follows that bypass the error above on `QNX`. And no build-time error occurs on `Ubuntu` (`Quantal`) too (I don't know if there's any runtime misbehavior):

```
x if(NOT (APPLE OR WIN32 OR MINGW OR ANDROID))
o if(NOT (APPLE OR WIN32 OR MINGW OR ANDROID OR UNIX))
```

Although I'm not sure if `UNIX` symbol is recognized by `cmake` on Ubuntu/Linux, succeeding this even on Ubuntu made me wonder why linking to `rt` is needed in `catkin` level.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66978/what-for-catkin-needs-to-link-to-librt-(realtime-extension)?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-07-09

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I don't know for sure, I'm pretty confident that catkin itself does not need librt, as it is just a set of cmake files topped with a handful of scripts.

Besides, using `UNIX` here seems inadequate, as it will disable linking against librt for Linux too. The toolchain file for QNX (if you are using one) most likely defines the `QNX` macro that you can use instead of `UNIX` in the `rt.cmake` file.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-07-10**:
I agree that using `UNIX` symbol like I cited might be a bad idea (although whether it influences `linux` is not clear to me). And I don't explicitly use `toolchain` file for `QNX` but will look for it if there's anything.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I randomly run into this issue every once in a while (every few months). Cleaning and cleanly rebuilding the package that throws the error generally appears to solve the problem. It would still be interesting to know if there is some sort of faulty CMake usage or so that can cause the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1